# Highcharts : Multiple sections within the same column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been using `Highcharts` in my project, and it has been immensely useful, great product.

However, I have a custom requirement now.

I have a leave calendar, where in I'm showing the 12 months on the `x axis` and number of days of leaves on the `y axis`.

Here comes the catch, there can be 3 types of leaves within a month:

**Submitted**

**Manager Approved**

**Approved**

For this I'm preparing data with 3 different `arrays` in the backend, and using these 3 arrays within the series section.

The data gets populated, the chart gets generated and things are fine.
There is a certain requirement over here, as below:

Lets suppose in month of January, a person has 3 sets of **APPROVED** leaves:

**First Set 3-4 January**

**Second Set 9-13 January**

**Third Set 20-25 January**

The requirement says that within a single column (a single type of leave), there should be some classification to denote multiple sets of leaves, i.e. either the single column chart can have multiple colors/widths, I mean something to visually classify them.

[image]

Please have a look at the attached image.

The **red column** denotes **Approved** Leaves, while **yellow column** denotes **Submitted/Manager Approved** Leaves.

The tooltip on the month of March shows 2 different sets of leaves, but the column height is basically the sum of the leave amounts, i.e (0.5+1=1.5).

**Here itself if somehow both these different sets of leaves have some demarcation, with different colors/widths then it would be visually more appealing and will be user friendly as well.**

I am attaching the code below for further reference.

```
<div id="leaveContainer" style="height:200px"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    callLeaves();
});

function callLeaves()
{
var leaveData={"SubmittedLeaves":[{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"January","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"February","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"March","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"April","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"May","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"June","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"July","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"August","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"September","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"October","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"November","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"December","LeaveId":null}],"ApprovedLeaves":[{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"January","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"February","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 0.50 day<br/>Start Date: 03/03/2017 End Date: 03/03/2017 <br/><br/> Approved Leaves 1.00 day<br/>Start Date: 20/03/2017 End Date: 20/03/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"20/03/2017","LeaveAmount":1.50,"MonthName":"March","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 1.00 day<br/>Start Date: 18/04/2017 End Date: 18/04/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"18/04/2017","LeaveAmount":1.00,"MonthName":"April","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 7.00 days<br/>Start Date: 03/05/2017 End Date: 11/05/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"11/05/2017","LeaveAmount":7.00,"MonthName":"May","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 2.00 days<br/>Start Date: 19/06/2017 End Date: 20/06/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"20/06/2017","LeaveAmount":2.00,"MonthName":"June","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"July","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"August","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 10.00 days<br/>Start Date: 18/09/2017 End Date: 29/09/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"29/09/2017","LeaveAmount":10.00,"MonthName":"September","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 0.50 day<br/>Start Date: 02/10/2017 End Date: 02/10/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"02/10/2017","LeaveAmount":0.50,"MonthName":"October","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"November","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"December","LeaveId":null}],"ManagerApprovedLeaves":[{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"January","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"February","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"March","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves 1.00 day<br/>Start Date: 28/04/2017 End Date: 28/04/2017 <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"28/04/2017","LeaveAmount":1.00,"MonthName":"April","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"May","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"June","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"July","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"August","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"September","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"October","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"November","LeaveId":null},{"LeaveStartDate":"<br/> Approved Leaves  days<br/>Start Date:  End Date:  <br/>","LeaveEndDate":"","LeaveAmount":0.0,"MonthName":"December","LeaveId":null}]};
displayLeaveDetails(JSON.parse(leaveData));
}

function convertToJsonObjectArray(data) {
        var arrayData = new Array();
        $.each(data, function (i) {
            var objdata = new Object();
            if (data[i] != undefined)
            {
                objdata.leaveStartDate = data[i]["LeaveStartDate"]
                objdata.leaveEndDate = data[i]["LeaveEndDate"];
                objdata.y = data[i]["LeaveAmount"];
                objdata.monthName = data[i]["MonthName"]
                objdata.leaveId = data[i]["LeaveId"]
            }
            arrayData.push(objdata);
        });
        return arrayData;
    }

function displayLeaveDetails(data) {
        var submittedLeaves = data[0]['SubmittedLeaves'];
        var managerApprovedLeaves = data[0]['ManagerApprovedLeaves'];
        var approvedLeaves = data[0]['ApprovedLeaves'];

        submittedLeaves = convertToJsonObjectArray(submittedLeaves);
        managerApprovedLeaves = convertToJsonObjectArray(managerApprovedLeaves);
        approvedLeaves = convertToJsonObjectArray(approvedLeaves);

        Highcharts.chart('leaveContainer', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Leaves'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Leaves (days)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.point.leaveStartDate;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Submitted Leaves',
                data: submittedLeaves,
                color: '#FFFF00'

            }, {
                name: 'Manager Approved Leaves',
                data: managerApprovedLeaves,
                color: '#FFFF00'

            }, {
                name: 'Approved Leaves',
                data: approvedLeaves,
                color: '#FF0000'
            }]
        });
    }
```

Please guide on this issue, any pointers or any alternate chart will also be useful.

Thanks

Comment: So you would like to have different colors in your column that will be related to different 'leaves' periods? You should be able to use stacked column in your case. Simple example of stacked Highcharts chart: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/

Comment: I prepared example for you, based on what @GrzegorzBlachliński said: http://jsfiddle.net/a5basrbL/.